# Error "attempt to apply non-function" in R while trying to make a loop

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm trying to make a loop for a time series, but I get the error

```
attempt to apply non-function
```

Does anybody know what I can do to fix this?

```
patient<-read.csv("Consecutive.csv",sep=";",dec=",")
pat3<-patient[1:3,]
patient3<-data.frame(pat3)

for (i in 1:128) {
  AgP(i)<-ts(pat3$X(i),frequency = 1)
  plot.ts(AgP(i))
}
```

I'm not sure how to add my datafile for you

Comment: You could do `dput(head(patient))` and copy/paste the output into your question to show us the structure of your data.

Comment: You are getting this specific error because you are using parenthesis instead of square brackets to subset `AgP` and `pat3$X`. R thinks you are trying to call functions called `AgP` and `pat3$X`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably lies here:

```
pat3$X(i)
```

You are accessing vector elements using `()`when it should be `[]`.

There is one more thing that looks odd. With `pat3<-patient[1:3,]` you extract the first *three* rows. Then you try to access `i in 1:128` values when there can only be three.

Comment: It's worse than that. `AgP(i)` should probably be `AgP[i]` too, but even then `AgP` doesn't exist. Also, in each cycle of the loop, the OP is trying to create a time series with a single event and plot it.